# How to balance REST api and Openedness to prevent data stealing

Tags: rest, backbone.js

One of our web site is a common "Announce for free your apartment".
Revenues are directly associated to number of public usage and announces
registered (argument of our marketing department).

On the other side, REST pushes to maintain a clear api when designing your
api (argument of our software department) which is a data stealing 
invitation to any competitors.  In this view, the web server becomes
almost an intelligent database.

We clearly identified our problem, but have no idea how to resolve these
contraints.  Any tips would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throttle the calls to the data rich elements by IP to say 1000 per day (or triple what a normal user would use)

If you expose data then it can be stolen. And think about search elements that return large datasets even if they are instigated by javascript or forms - I personally have written trawlers that circumvent these issues.

You may also think (if data is that important) about decrypting it in the client based on keys and authentication sent from the server (but this only raises the bar not the ability to steal.

Add captcha/re-captcha for users who are scanning too quickly or too much.

In short:

- As always only expose the minimum API to do the job (attack surface minimisation)
- Log and throttle
- Force sign in(?). This at least MAY put off some scanners
- Use capthca mechanism for users you think may be bots trawling your data